# How to get date in mm/dd/yyyy format in output of CONCATENATE function

Tags: excel

I have an excel with first column (A1) as date and B1 as Description
I need to show a text in C1 by generating a string using A1 and B1 columns in the format of (Description on Date)

I am trying to use CONCATENATE function to achieve this

e.g.

```
A1         B1           C1
9/3/2016   Weekend      =CONCATENATE(B1," on ",A1)
```

When I wrote formula in C1 as =CONCATENATE(B1,A1) it resulted saying "Weekend on 42616".

How to get result in expected format which should be like  "Weekend on 9/3/2016".

Comment: got it , i didn't find it, although my question is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use the TEXT function in formula to convert number to given date format as below:

```
C1
=CONCATENATE(B1," on ",TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Comment: @pnuts you are right, that was type mistake, i corrected it. shorter one is good.